# assign maximum values for rows in several dataframes to a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes called dfOne and dfTwo have the same number or rows.
dfOne contains several columns including colA, colB and colMax
dfTwo contains several columns including colH

For each row i want to assign the maximum of colA, colB and colH to colMax

```
dfOne.colMax = dfOne[['colA', 'colB']].min(axis=1)
```

(Remark: is there a syntax that uses dfOne.colA and dfOne.colB instead of dfOne[['colA', 'colB']] ?)

seems to be a partly solution.

But I can't combine that with the minimum of dfTwo.colH and assigning it to dfOne.colMax

I tried variations of

```
    dfOne.colMax = max(dfTwo.colH, dfOne[['colA', 'colB']].min(axis=1))
```

and using numpy.maximum as well after reading several other posts.
But none of those posts deals with two dataframes and I can't find how to do that.

If I use

```
dfOne.colMax = dfTwo.colH
dfOne.colMax = max(dfTwo.colH, dfOne[['colA', 'colB', 'colMax']].min(axis=1))
```

I get results but I suppose it can be done better.

How should this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate like this:

```
dfOne['colMax'] = pd.concat([dfOne[['colA', 'colB']], dfTwo['colH']], axis=1).max(axis=1)
```

Comment: I prefer a one line solution over mine but that has to be almost as fast or faster. I think your solution takes substantial more time. nevertheless: thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
dfOne = pd.DataFrame({'colA' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                    'colB' : [4, 5, 1, 3, 8, 9]
                    })

dfTwo= pd.DataFrame({'colH' : [3, 6, 4, 8, 2, 3]})

dfOne['colMax'] = dfOne.apply(lambda x: max(min(x['colA'], x['colB']), dfTwo.iloc[x.name]['colH']), axis = 1)

print(dfOne)

    colA  colB  colMax
0     1     4       3
1     2     5       6
2     3     1       4
3     4     3       8
4     5     8       5
5     6     9       6
```

Comment: For larger frames apply can get very slow when using custom functions.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I should have provided that myself. I modified your solution to dfOne['colMax'] = dfOne.apply(lambda x: max(x['colA'], x['colB'], dfTwo.iloc[x.name]['colH']), axis = 1)
 and it works but (indeed) as Physmatik wrote it takes quite some time for larger dataframes. In my case the dataframe is about 2000 rows maximum.

Comment: @SoftwareTester: I agree with you and Physmatik. But in your problem we have to update the each row values based on calculation of 2 different tables. So, inherently this is row-wise calculation. And , as per my understanding, `apply` is the way to do it. Also, 2K is not a large data size and `apply` will not affect the performance. But performance will get affected if you are using `1M` rows observations.